# MySQL - PHP, подключение есть, изменений нет.

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, господа. Столкнулся с невероятной для меня проблемой. Есть база данных, на хостинге. Подключение сайта - базы данных успешно, но добавление в базу данных не происходит(Регистрация пользователей). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, который производит подключение и вставку записей. Желательно схему таблицы. Вставьте после строк создания подключения и выполнения запроса вывод последней ошибки mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Причин может быть великое множество, желательно предоставить код. Но в большинстве случаев причина в некорректном SQL-запросе, попробуйте сделать следующее:

- поместите текст запроса в переменную;
- выведете значение переменной в браузер;
- скопируйте из браузера запрос и вставьте текст запроса в    окно
  запросов PHPMyAdmin на хостинге - если запрос успешно пройдет,    то
  проблема в другом месте и нужно смотреть код программ, если не
  пройдет, то PHPMyAdmin покажет в каком месте у вас ошибка.